# How to draw a polygon in matlab in a 2D matrix

Tags: image, matlab, 2d, polygon

I have the follow code in matlab which is supposed to draw a polygon on a image (has to be a 2d image, be just a patch).

```
numCorners=8;
dotPos=[];
for rr=1:numCorners
   dotPos(end+1)=(cos(rr/numCorners*2*pi))*100;
   dotPos(end+1)=(sin(rr/numCorners*2*pi))*100;
end


BaseIm=zeros(1000,1000);
dotpos=[500,500];
imageMatrix =drawpolygon(BaseIm, dotPos, 1); or how else do draw a white polygon here?
imshow(imageMatrix);
```

This doesn't work as drawpolygon does not appear to exist in this way any idea how to do this?

Note that the resulting data must be an image of equal size of baseIM and must be an array of doubles (ints can be converted) as this is test data for another algorithm.

I have since found the inpolygon(xi,yi,xv,yv); function which I could combine with a for loop if I knew how to properly call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to plot two polygons, you can use the [fill](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) function.

```
t=0:2*pi;
x=cos(t)*2;
y=sin(t)*2

fill(x,y,'r')
hold on
fill(x/2,y/2,'g')
```

As an alternative, you can use the [patch](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/patch.html?searchHighlight=patch) function:

```
figure
t=0:2*pi;
x=cos(t)*2;
y=sin(t)*2

patch(x,y,'c')
hold on
patch(x/2,y/2,'k')
```

[image]

**Edit**

The `fill` and `patch` functions allow to add polygons also over an actual image too.

```
% Load an image on the axes
imshow('Jupiter_New_Horizons.jpg')
hold on
% Get the axis limits (just to center the polygons
x_lim=get(gca,'xlim')
y_lim=get(gca,'ylim')
% Create the polygon's coords
t=0:2*pi;
x=cos(t)*50+x_lim(2)/2;
y=sin(t)*50+y_lim(2)/2
% Add the two polygons to the image
f1_h=fill(x,y,'r')
hold on
f1_h=fill(x/2,y/2,'g')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I specifically need my data to be placed on an image (2d array of size 1000 by 1000 to be precise) as this is for test data for another algorithm. Fill and Patch seem to generate 1 by 1 data describing the points.

Comment: I do not understand your comment: with reference to the code I've posted, you can consider the first polygon (the red one) as your 2D array and the second one (the green one) the polygon "added" on. The values returned by `fill` and `patch` are just `handles`.

Comment: I've updated the answer, by adding the possibility to add polygons over an image. Where did you get the `drawpolygon` function? It seems not be a MatLab function.

Comment: Well the patches contain vertices ext. However I want to test an edge detection algorithm in combination with noise (to be added later). So I do not want to just show an image I need an actual 2D array containing the data.